# ¿Se permite el triple signo de interrogación? Is "???" allowed?

Tags: ortografía, puntuación

Normalmente me molesta ver preguntas escritas con la siguiente puntuación frecuente en correos electrónicos:

> Y tú vas a ir????

Pero hoy noté que lo análogo con signos de admiración es posible:

> *c) En obras literarias es posible escribir dos o tres signos de exclamación para indicar mayor énfasis en la entonación exclamativa: ¡¡¡Traidor!!!*
>   Fuente: [lema.rae.es](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=bH8aKhoE1D6eF5Wp4C).

Entonces ¿es posible un doble o triple signo de interrogación?

Comment: Relacionado con esta pregunta, también veo mucho el uso de puntos suspensivos con cuatro o cinco puntos....

Comment: jajaja @Diego, pero si bien a primera vista he dudado con lo de los interrogantes, lo de los puntos siempre me ha parecido muy, muy incorrecto (aunque enfático)

Answer (score 4):

Dado que las [reglas que citas](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=bH8aKhoE1D6eF5Wp4C) explican que se puede hacer con los signos de exclamación como una excepción o uso especial y no dice nada sobre los de interrogación debemos entender que, por lo menos de momento, **ese tipo de uso no está recogido o permitido**.

Entiendo que se pueden poner varios signos de exclamación para dar más énfasis (estás realmente interesado en la respuesta a tu pregunta). Siempre puedes gritar más y más alto, pero no puedes "preguntar más".

Comment: Lo usan como para darle mas importancia a la pregunta. Si escribieran "?!!!" creo que seria un poco raro. Igual no es un uso formal. Un caso en que he visto que lo usan es cuando tienen varias preguntas en el texto (mail) suelen resaltar una de ellas con varios signos de interrogacion.

Comment: "no puedes preguntar más" - ... ¿seguro? - Si. - ¿pero... seguro? - ¡Que si! - pero, ¿¿¿seguro??? (hay que leer esto enfatizando cada vez mas la U de seguro) xD

Answer (score 3):

Yo creo que para hablar de lo que está "correcto" o "permitido" tú mismo ya pusiste la mejor referencia posible en el artículo de la RAE, donde aparecen claramente todas las posibilidades y obligaciones de estos signos de puntuación. Ahí no se menciona el uso de varios signos de interrogación y se aclara que en el caso de los de exclamación múltiple, es lenguaje literario. O sea, no se debe usar.

Además, la respuesta de Diego nos deja más que clara la lógica del asunto: no se puede multiplicar la intensidad de una pregunta.

Sin embargo, no creo que haya ningún problema en usar cualquier recurso disponible para dar más expresividad al lenguaje informal. (Esto es una opinión).

Si escribes un artículo periodístico, una circular para tu empresa, un informe, un blog, una respuesta para StackExchange, etc., es indispensable apegarse a todas las reglas posibles porque tus interlocutores son variados y necesitan un mensaje estandarizado, con toda la ayuda explícita posible para decodificar correctamente.

Pero en la conversación familiar no creo que haya nada grave en "saltarse" reglas blandas.

Así como en el lenguaje oral disponemos de juegos de entonación, modificaciones de las pausas y todos los gestos y ademanes del mundo, en el lenguaje escrito disponemos de tipografías, signos de puntuación e íconos.

Si para expresarme quiero usar flechitas, íconos tipográficos o MAYÚSCULAS, ¡¡¡bienvenidos sean!!!........ ;) , siempre y cuando el receptor sea la persona adecuada. (Por supuesto que no vamos a agregar aquí los errores, que son los que empobrecen la comunicación, como confusión de letras, mal vocabulario, desorden, ausencia de puntos, etc.)

En definitiva, si en un correo electrónico te multiplican los signos de interrogación no es nada grave. Todo lo contrario: te dejan claro de una forma simple y expresiva que no es una pregunta cualquiera, sino que por algún contexto que ustedes dos manejan, es una pregunta más importante o compleja.

Answer (score 3):

Recolectando la información de las otras respuestas creo que, como se esperaba, no debe estar permitida tal exageración.

Por si eso no fuese convincente, creo que hay un par de probables orígenes del múltiple signo de interrogación.

1. *Enfatizar que se trata de una pregunta.* ¿Puede ser que un solo signo pase inadvertido? El español tiene dos. Estoy seguro que si se agrega el primero (lo cual de hecho es la única forma correcta de preguntar) se disminuyen las probabilidades de que el lector (letrado o no) no lo perciba.

   > ¿Y tú vas a ir?
2. *Querer expresar sorpresa*. Si no se hallasen los signos para expresar que uno está sorprendido y pregunta al mismo tiempo, la solución no es una repetición de los signos de pregunta, sino combinar estos con los de sorpresa usando **¿¡ (texto) !?**, como en este ejemplo:

   > -Hoy es el entierro de mi amante. Ahí estará su esposa.
   >   -¿¡Y tú vas a ir!?
3. *Apurar al interlocutor.* Ésta quizá sea otra razón. Incluso es común algo así como `?!?!?!`. Nuevamente los signos de interrogación son suficientes; quizá agregar el texto "*es urgente*", mas tantos signos no son necesarios.

Comment: Creo que hay un tercer uso que es "meter prisa". En un chat el usuario podría poner 15 signos de interrogación seguidos para expresar que está ansioso por obtener la respuesta: "vas a ir??? cntxt vamos!!!!!"

Comment: NB https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrobang

Answer (score 3):

No. Como bien apuntas, está aceptado el uso de múltiples signos de exclamación, pero no de interrogación.

Según explica la RAE en su web en una entrada de julio de 2019 titulada precisamente [¿Se pueden repetir los signos de interrogación y exclamación?](https://www.rae.es/noticias/se-pueden-repetir-los-signos-de-interrogacion-y-exclamacion):

> Los signos de exclamación pueden repetirse para aportar énfasis («¡¡¡Traidor!!!»); los de interrogación, en cambio, no, pero pueden combinarse con los de exclamación («¿¡Cómo!?»; «¡¿Qué?!»).

Por tanto, en tu caso se podría escribir algo así como *¿¡¡¡Y tú vas a ir!!!?* o bien algo menos estrepitoso como *¿Y tú vas a ir!*.